# Email notifications from OEM

Tags: oracle-enterprise-manager

I am trying to generate email alerts from OEM to multiple email addresses. I have configured the SMTP server details from 'Setup' screen. And then I have added the email addresses under the 'Preferences' tab in OEM.
To check if the alerts are working fine, I have shutdown database and restarted 3/4 times. But only once the alerts notification came and that too only to one email address and not to all the email ids mentioned.

Please let me know why this is working in this way. Also, am I missing anything?? Do I need to add anything else to get the notification emails correctly for all the email ids??

Also, there is one screen for notification schedule. Do I have to define some schedule???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to fill in the notification schedule. This site defines to whom the mail will be sent on which time and day. If you shut down your database at a time, where no mail-address is set in the schedule, OEM will not send any mails.

You can fill in multiple mail addresses in the field for the schedule to have multiple persons receiving alert mails.

If you want the same addresses to be used every time, set the start and end so that 24 hours are covered and select all weekdays.

For testing the SMTP-Server, there is a link on the site, where you define one to send a test-mail.

The purpose of the notification schedule is e.g. for having different persons to be notified during working hours than at night.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when we needed to add a new hired administrator to receive the alerts.
The steps:

1. Add the e-mail to the 'Enterprise Manager Password & Email'
2. Check the incidents rules who should receive the alerts (we had two pd and non-pd special OEM groups AKA administrators, who receive the alerts). The path Setup->Incidents->Incidents Rules. We have two rules there for pd and non-pd; I verified the OEM administrator names, who should receive the alerts. I did not change anything there; just took the administrator's names.
3. Go to the Setup->Security->Administrators. Add the new account to these two groups.
4. The user started receiving the e-mails :)